# How to convert string to array using explode yii2

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

anybody can help me to convert string -> array using explode? I'm on learning yii2 framework now. I tried to build dependent dropdown.

My function in controller for ajax call

```
public function actionRequestApplication($ID_APPLICATION)
    {
        $output = '';
        $items = APPLICATION::findAll(['ID' => $ID_APPLICATION]);
        foreach($items as $item) {
            // $content = explode(', ', $item->CONNECTOR_PARAM);
            $content = sprintf('%s', $item->CONNECTOR_PARAM);
            $output .= \yii\helpers\Html::tag('option', $content, ['value' => $item->ID]);
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

My dependent dropdown worked properly if i choose ID_APPLICATION, second select show a CONNECTOR_PARAM. In database CONNECTOR_PARAM field :

ID | NAME | CONNECTOR_PARAM
1  | Indra| create, update, read, delete

I want if i choose ID_APPLICATION, second select can choose as array.

**UPDATED**

i have changed my controller function like this

```
public function actionRequestApplication($ID_APPLICATION)
    {
        $output = '';
        $items = APPLICATION::findAll(['ID' => $ID_APPLICATION]);
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $content = explode(', ', $item['CONNECTOR_PARAM']);
            $output .= \yii\helpers\Html::tag('option', $content, ['value' => $item->ID]);
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

But i get 'Array to string convertion', How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

findAll returns a list of active record models that match the specified primary key value(s) or a set of column values.

so items contans all the APPLICATION model (activeRecord) that match you condition  you could refer to the model content  as $item->CONNECTOR_PARAM

```
public function actionRequestApplication($ID_APPLICATION)
    {
        $output = '';
        $items = APPLICATION::findAll(['ID' => $ID_APPLICATION]);
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $content = explode(', ', $item->CONNECTOR_PARAM);
            $output = \yii\helpers\Html::tag('option', $content, ['value' => $item->ID]);
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

but you are concatenate the $content  (an array  ) to the tag helper ( are you sure ? could be you need just  a simply assign alias change .= to =)

And last You should not use comma separated  value in a column (with the need  of an explode function for obtain the single element list) 
but normalize correctly these value in a proper related  table